# Cannot choose new data source from ReportViewer control

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.0

I'm following an ASP.NET tutorial about *Reporting Services*. I am at a point where I add a `ReportViewer` control to my `aspx` page. From there I have to select the report that I want to use and add a new `Datasource`. But adding the datasource is where I'm having trouble.

The tutorial says I have to choose: `Choose Data Sources` from the `ReportViewer` and then select: 'New data source`. But I don't seem to have that option.

This is from the tutorial:

[image]

And this is what I see:

[image]

So now I'm stuck with this. Anyone any idea how to solve this problem>

Comment: I just created a blank page, added a reportViewer, created a new report, created a strong typed dataset, added a productTable to this dataset, **compiled**, _added the dataset to the report_, switched back to the reportViewer and found the screenshot from the tutorial you mentioned. tl;dr - i tried it, it worked for me. Please provide link to your tutorial

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz Hi, this is the tutorial i'm referring to (scroll to **Defining the data sources.**): http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-a-asp-net-interactive-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are using Visual Studio 2012 but in that tutorial Visual Studio 2010 is used.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the draw, but this is due to a defect present in VS2012 and VS2013, which is mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961293/visual-studio-2012-crashed-while-adding-data-source-to-report-viewer). The issue can be tracked via [this Microsoft Connect bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812807/visual-studio-crashes-when-selecting-a-report-viewers-datasource), and the workaround it mentions on [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2014/01/16/visual-studio-2012-and-2013-crashes-when-you-bind-datasource-to-rdlc-from-report-viewer-web-control.aspx) should be adaptable to this situation as well

Alternately, the issue does not occur for Web *Site* projects found under File -> New Web Site (Alt+Shift+N), which might be suitable for tutorial purposes

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, I have had the same issue and managed to resolve by installing the reportviewer runtime: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35747

Now I have the option to create a new datasource in Visual Studio, hope this helps someone