# Visual Studio 2012 crashed while adding data source to report viewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create rdlc report in vs 2012 ultimate. report was working fine on vs 2010. Now problem is: Visual studio crashed (closed) when I try to add data source in report viewer.

any suggestion to resolve this issue. Is this a known error in vs 2012 ultimate ?

Comment: We have encountered several very annoying problems with VS2012. Some projects are forced to remain in VS2010. VS2012 is a buggy, problematic product from my view.

Comment: Same issue here. Everytime I select the option "New -> Dataset..." or right-click on "Datasets" and select "Add dataset..." it crashes instantly. Not sure what can I do to solve this..

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same error, then I removed the PdfSharp and MigraDoc libraries from the project.

No errors anymore.

EDIT:

Actually, the error was in the source control.

PdfSharp.Charting was removed but the project still was refer it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a known issue in both Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013, it is mentioned in [this Microsoft Connect bug.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812807/visual-studio-crashes-when-selecting-a-report-viewers-datasource)

A workaround has been posted [on this MSDN blog.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2014/01/16/visual-studio-2012-and-2013-crashes-when-you-bind-datasource-to-rdlc-from-report-viewer-web-control.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.  I was able to add reports to a new project so I knew there was a problem with my project.  After much trial and error I determined that I had some unnecessary references that got carried over from an older project.  The references were not correct and were missing some dependencies.  After deleting these references my problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this fault after migrating a project from VS2010 to VS2012 recently.

The fix that work for me was to open the .rdlc in a text editor, and look for the tags that contain the path to the dataset used in the report. They looked like this:

```
<rd:SchemaPath>.......some path.....</rd:SchemaPath>
```

In my case the path was the old path to where the source was previously kept when I was working in VS2010. I had changed the location of the project on my PC and this path was now invalid.

So I updated the path to the correct location, saved the RDLC, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I debug and found that if you download VS- Command the problem is resolved