# Visual Studio is closed When choosing data source in choose data source window

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a report in `Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate`. I create my `.rdlc` file. Then I add a `ReportViewer` to my `.aspx` page. Then I select `SmartTag` of `ReportViewer` and select the `.rdlc` file. After that I select `Choose Data Source`. When I select my data source `Visual Studio` is closed without any error message. I tried this in `Visual Studio 2010` without any problem. Is this a bug in `Visual Studio 2012`? Or I'm doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961293/visual-studio-2012-crashed-while-adding-data-source-to-report-viewer) where a [workaround](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2014/01/16/visual-studio-2012-and-2013-crashes-when-you-bind-datasource-to-rdlc-from-report-viewer-web-control.aspx) and a [Microsoft Connect bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/812807/visual-studio-crashes-when-selecting-a-report-viewers-datasource) are mentioned

Answer (score -1):

I actually just solved this problem in my own app, so I thought I'd pop over and share.

The problem in my case was that the form (in your case it would be the .aspx page) had the same name as the data source, and it was creating a circular dependency. Change one of the names, and presto! Worked a treat!

Comment: This has nothing to do with it. Simply create a new ASPX page, drop a ReportViewer COntrol in, map up a report, and then "Choose Data Source" as desribed above, and VS DOES NOT crash, it ismply closes your form, and then closes the application.